# Grafana K8s microservices availability dashboard based on actuator uptime

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, sre, grafana

I need to create a dashboard that is using micrometer prometheus spring actuator endpoint to show all services for a given namespaces in green boxes or red boxes depending on status, the boxes should contain the service names.
Now I am trying to decouple currently https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/4701 and somehow build the dashboard I need, but I face many challengers, the first one is replacing ips with service names. I don't want to mess up with services code, I have just added the micrometer dependency in a common template that is inherited.
The way I see it I feel like it is impossible that nobody has created a publicly available dashboard or a guide, but I couldn't find one.